# Use Green's Theorem to calculate function.

Tags: calculus

> To Find: Use Green's Theorem to calculate
>   $$\int_C y\tan^2x\, dx + \tan x \, dy$$
>   where $C$ is the circle $x^2+(y+1)^2=1$
>   $$\left \{  y\tan^2x\right \}_y=\frac{y^2}{2}\tan^2x$$
>   $$\left \{ \tan x \right \}_x=-\log{\cos (x)}$$
>   $$\int_C y\tan^2x\, dx + \tan x \, dy=\iint_R-\log\cos (x)-\frac{y^2}{2}\tan^2x \, dA$$
>   {I need limits} - where to from here?

Comment: These derivatives are wrong.

Comment: You have written down the integrals of those coefficient functions instead of the derivatives. If you calculate the derivatives correctly, then you will find the following identity very helpful! $$1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivatives are wrong.

Green Theorem says
$$
\int_{C} P\,dx+Q\,dy=\int\!\!\!\int_D\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\,dA,
$$
where $C$ is the boundary curve of $D$.
Here $P=y\tan^2x$, $Q=\tan x$. So 
$$
Q_x=\frac1{\cos^2x},\ \ \ P_y=\tan^2x.
$$
Then 
$$
Q_x-P_y=\frac1{\cos^2x}-\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}=1
$$
Thus
$$
\int_{C} y\tan^2 x\,dx+\tan x\,dy=\int\!\!\!\int_D1\,dA=\text{Area}(D)=\pi,
$$
since $D$ is a disk of radius 1.